# Maximum subgroups of array so that it can be independently sorted

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

For an array, I need to find the maximum number of subgroups that can be created so that - when all of them are individually sorted and then placed sequentially one after the other, the entire array gets sorted.

For eg:
Array `[1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 12, 13, 14]`

The max number of groups that can be formed are **6**

`[1], [5, 4], [9, 8, 7], [12], [13], [14]`

If we were to sort the internal elements independently and then place the groups together, we'd get a sorted array.

Another example would be `[4, 3, 2, 6, 1]` where the max groups can be formed is only **1** (array itself)

Note that all elements of array are **distinct**. The program I wrote was written on the following pseudocode-

```
1. Save all elements of array A into hashmap with the element value A[i] as key 
   and index i as value
2. Sort array A.
3. Initialize groupCount = 0, startIndex = -1;
3. For every element, check from hashmap if its original index is 
   greater than **startIndex**. If it is greater, increment groupCount 
   and set startIndex = original index of element i.
4. Finally return groupCount;
```

This logic failed to work on a lot of test cases. Could you help me figure out what's the optimal logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is **nearly** right. You are incrementing the group count whenever the original index is greater than starting index. This will fail in many cases like: `5 6 3 4`.

*Working of your code*

- In the above array(i.e `5 6 3 4`), It will check the original index of 5 which should be **2**(in sorted order) & will increment the group Count to 1 alongside setting the starting index to 2
- When it will check the original index of 6 which should be **3**(in sorted order), it will increment the group Count(**2**) since its index is greater than starting index(i.e 2). Which is incorrect since the answer is **1**!!.

*Improvements*

You should change the starting index from 2 to 3 when you encounter 6 without changing the group Count & should increment the group count **only** when **starting index = original index**.

Here is my Code with **O(NlogN)** complexity:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int maxSubGroups(vector<int>arr){
    int n=arr.size();
    vector<int>sortedArr = arr;
    sort(sortedArr.begin(), sortedArr.end());
    map<int,int>m;
    for(int i=0;i<sortedArr.size();i++)
        m[sortedArr[i]]=i;
    int maxGroups = 0, maxIndex=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        maxIndex = max(maxIndex, m[arr[i]]);
        if(maxIndex == i)
            maxGroups++;
    }
    return maxGroups;
}

int main() {
    vector<int>arr = {1, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7, 12, 13, 14};
    int maxGroups = maxSubGroups(arr);
    cout<<maxGroups; // 6
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live Code**](https://ideone.com/f1N7nl)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you can end the current group as soon as the set of elements it contains is the same as the set of elements that appear on the respective positions in the sorted array.

The above idea can be directly implemented in **O**(N^2), but it is useful to convert it in the following observation, easier to implement efficiently (it might require taking a moment to realize why the above statement implies the next one):

- The maximum number of groups is equal to the number of indices *k*, such that the first *k* elements in the sequence are exactly the smallest *k* ones.

This is easier to implement, because in order to check whether the smallest *k* + 1 items are precisely the first *k* + 1 ones from the original array, we can only look at the largest original index among the smallest *k* + 1 items. If this largest index is *k*, then we necessarily have the set of indices 0, 1, ... *k* occurring on these first positions.

The pseudocode below details this approach. The time complexity is **O**(N log(N)), determined by the sorting step.

```
1. Save all elements of array A into a hashmap with the element value A[i] as key 
   and index i as value
2. Sort array A.
3. Initialize groupCount = 0, maxIndex = -1;
4. For k = 0 to N,
       check from hashmap the original index i, of A[k]
       maxIndex = max(i, maxIndex)
       if maxIndex == k then increment groupCount
5. Finally return groupCount;
```